# Set clicklistener for ListFragment

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-listfragment

I have a "modell" class which defines the structure and values of my list, called Application. Now in my ListFragment class I am trying to get the title that has been clicked in the listrow. Following the code that I currently have:

Aplication class:

```
public class Application {
    private String title;
    private long totalDl;
    private String rating;
    private String icon;


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public long getTotalDl() {
        return totalDl;
    }
    public void setTotalDl(long totalDl) {
        this.totalDl = totalDl;
    }
    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;

    }
}
```

ListFragment class with the clicklistener section:

```
public class NewUploadsFragment extends ListFragment {

private Application app;
...

@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "Item " + app.getTitle() + " was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
}
```

But it does not work, I'll get an error. So my question is if anybody knows how I can show the clicked "title" of the listrow **1. with the Application class** and **2. without the Application class?**

Thanks guys!

Comment: There is no **Activity** class in your code, which is the fundamental to actually display a list. Please refer to basic Android tutorials: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the String from the ListRow by using View.

```
// listening to single list item on click
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
      //in this example "name" is the item from row you want to display
      TextView ptitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
      String Title = ptitle.getText().toString();
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Item " + Title + " was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

Change the R.id.name to R.id."the view you want to display"

Answer (score 0):

You can use **onItemClickListener** like

```
public void onItemClickListener(AdapterView<?> obj,View v, int pos, long arg3) { 
Application app= (Application )obj.getItemAtPosition(pos);
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Item " + app.getTitle() + " was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and Also from **ArrayList** like

```
ArrayList<Application> listofObjects;
// add values to listofObjects
// set listAdapter
 .......
 .......
public void onItemClickListener(AdapterView<?> obj,View v, int pos, long arg3) 
{ 
  Application app= listofObjects.get(pos);
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Item " + app.getTitle() + " was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```